# UITextView with maximum width, unlimited height

Tags: ios, layout, uitextview

**Background**

I am trying to accomplish something that should be quite simple, I haven't found any question/answer that deals with just that, and frankly I don't want to go through the whole of TextKit just to implement this. So, If somebody happens to have done this before, and can provide a pointer, it would be great.

**The Problem**

I need a text view that:

1. Is created and placed programmatically where the user tapped,
2. Starts at zero width, and grows horizontally as the user enters text,
3. Also grows vertically to accommodate any new line when the user taps the return key,
4. Also adds a line break when the width reaches a preset maximum.

I have this code:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView)
{
    let text = textView.text

    let freeSize = (text as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : textView.font!])

    var width = freeSize.width > maximumTextViewWidth ? maximumTextViewWidth : freeSize.width

    width += (textView.textContainerInset.left + textView.textContainerInset.right)

    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max))

    var newFrame = textView.frame

    newFrame.size = newSize

    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

...However, the text view "breaks" after every two or so characters, long before the maximum preset width is reached, as if the width can't quite catch up with the displayed text.

I tried setting the text view's `textContainerInset` property to zero when I instantiate it, but I still get an extra line break at the beginning.